# Editing mode for kendogrid selected cell

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with 1 editable column, when I execute a certain javascript function I want to enable editing for the currently selected cell. The point is that this happens programmatically and not by clicking the cell. What the code currently does is select the cell that needs to be set to editing mode but doesn't enable the editing mode itself.

**Edit (fix):**

I had to change the index to the cell selection to +1 while the row selection stayed the same (probably because the header counts as a cell or something). There were also functions that took away the focus from the editing field which closed it instantly.

JS:

```
$('#txtBarcode').keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if (key == 13) {

        var grid = $("#PickListDetailGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataSource = $("#PickListDetailGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
        var allData = dataSource.data();
        var code = this.value;

        $.each(allData, function (index, item) {
            if (item.ArticleID == code) {
                console.log("index :" + index);                    
                var cell = grid.select("tr:eq(" + index + ") td:eq(" + (5) + ")");
                grid.editCell(cell); 
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Grid:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp1.Models.PickListLineViewModel>()
                        .Name("PickListDetailGrid")
                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(c => c.ArticleName);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.ArticleID);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.PickID);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.LineNum);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.PickedQuantity).HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "test" });
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Status);
                        })
                        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 75%;" })
                        .Scrollable()
                        .Groupable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .Selectable()
                        .RowAction(row =>
                        {
                            if (row.DataItem.Quantity == row.DataItem.PickedQuantity)
                            {
                                row.HtmlAttributes["class"] = "k-state-selected";
                            }
                        })
                        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                        {
                            toolbar.Custom().Text("Return to Picklists")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "color:black; width:100%; height:50%;" })
                            .Action("Picklist", "PickList");
                        })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .Events(events => events.Error("error"))
                .Model(model => model.Id(i => i.PickID))
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Field(f => f.PickID).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(f => f.ArticleID).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(f => f.LineNum).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(f => f.Quantity).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(f => f.ArticleName).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(f => f.Status).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(f => f.PickedQuantity).Editable(true);
                })
                .Read(read => read.Action("PickLines_Read", "PickList", new { name = "id", id = Model.FirstOrDefault().PickID }))
                .Update(update => update.Action("submitPickList", "PickList"))
        )
      .Events(events => events
        .Change("onChange")
        .Edit("onEdit")
        .Save("onSave"))
    )
```

On Edit:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    e.container.find("input").bind("focus", function () {
        if (this.style.display != "none") {
            var element = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                element.select();
            })
        }
    })

    setTimeout(function () {
        document.activeElement.select();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead:

```
var cell = grid.select("tr:eq(" + index + ") td:eq(" + (5) + ")");
grid.editCell(cell);
```

Try:

```
grid.editCell("tr:eq(" + index + ") td:eq(" + (5) + ")");
```

Comment: Could you also post your onEdit event definition?

Comment: I've added it to the main post, it currently makes sure that i automatically select the value upon opening the field with a mouseclick.

Comment: I've checked my solution programatically on clean example and it works. Are you sure your edit cell code block is reachable? No exceptions have occured? No undefined references? Did you try to edit example cell from console window?

Comment: Hmm it seems like the focus stays on the textbox after I press enter "$('#txtBarcode').keydown" I think its possible this causes the problem with it. it does reach the code however.

Comment: I've had a few lines which redirected the focus to the textbox in my code and I commented them all but the editCell() function still only gets selected instead of being set to editable.

Comment: Have you tried to manually invoke editCell in console window?

Comment: The only thing I get is editCell is not defined, I've also tried doing this in a fresh application however it still does not open the selected cell just selecting.

Comment: The problem was in the index adding +1 to it fixed it. The data collection starts counting at 0 while the grid starts at 1. Anyway thanks for the help building a fresh application and simplifying it down made me discover it.